# Print character array to console in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm having a problem when I try to parse a String to a char array.
Here is my code:

```
line = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(line);               
char line2[] = line.toCharArray();
System.out.println(line2.toString());
```

So, as you can see, it's a simple code.

The problem is: line contains the string "00000001010010110100100000100000", but when I use "line.toCharArray", my char array receives "[C@7e243eed".
I think it's receiving the line variable adress or something like that.

Could someone help me?
Thanks :D

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line2));`

Comment: You could also use `System.out.println(line2)` (without explicit `toString()` call). This would invoke overloaded [`println(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-char:A-) version of `println` which prints each character (without `[ , , , ]` array format).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I could do that :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` to `char` array conversion is fine, it's `Sysout` that prints `hash` of the array object instead of its content. If you want to print the array in user friendly way, use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line2));
```

Comment: Thanks, mate! I didn't know that.
In my code, there's another problem too... I was trying to create a new string using "String s = line2.toString()" (as I was doing inside the print), but instead I should use "String s = new String(line2)".
Thank you!